# Java control panel security options grayed out

Tags: windows-7, windows, java

We got an image to use as a baseline to deploy a series of VMs for desktop use, we had to configure for our use. Our network has no connection to the cloud so it's much less locked down than this image was so one of the things I had to do was make it easier for us to use, especially with some of our older software that are difficult to update.

One issue was we had a few devices that have interfaces that use java. A lot of these have various issues that get hit on Java's security. The previous image we used allowed us to switch between "very high" and "high" in the java security pane. This fixes the issue. Currently on this new image it's grayed out, so we cannot access any of these management sites.

I've tried numerous solutions after some extensive googling and finding where java's settings are stored but the (windows\sun\java\deployment) folder is empty.

Version of Java is Java 8 131. The version of Java on the old computer was Java 8 31. I looked through the changelogs and I didn't see anything that would block us from changing this.

Any ideas?

**Edit**:  contents of deployment.properties files in users folder: (hand jamming it since it's two different networks that don't have any cross talk)

```
deployment.modified.timestamp=1512079566693
deployment.expiration.decision.timestamp.11.131.2=1512067199
deployment.roaming.profile=false
deployment.version=8
deployment.expiration.decision.suppression.11.131.2=false
deployment.expiration.decision.11.131.2=later
install.disable.sponsor.offers=false
deployment.browser.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe

deployment.javaws.jre.1.location=(java website it has no access to)
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=
deployment.javaws.jre.0.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=
deployment.javaws.jre.1.enabled=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osarch=amd64
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osname=Windows
deployment.javaws.jre.1.product=1.8.0_131
deployment.javaws.jre.0.platform=1.8
deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre8\\bin\\javaw.exe
deployment.javaws.jre.0.location=(java website as above, no access to this)
deployment.javaws.jre.0.enabled=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osarch=x86
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osname=Windows
deployment.javaws.jre.1.platform=1.8
deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.8.0_131
```

(maybe some typos in there)

Comment: The inability to change this security setting is likely an intentional change by the person who created the Windows image.  I am going to assume you are not an Administrator.  If you do have access to an Administrator user, then running [javacpl.exe](https://java.com/en/download/help/javacpl.xml) as an Administrator, will allow you to change this particular setting.

Comment: I do have admin, it's joined to the domain and we've used more than one admin account. I also went directly to the javacpl file directly and ran it as administrator and it still wasn't working.

Comment: So you are saying you launched elevated the permissions of javacpl.exe to that of an Administrator, and the settings still could not be changed, if that is the case then you are running into a group policy.  Updated your question to  provide the settings to any Java related group policies that have been configured.  It sounds like while there isn't a  system level deployment configuration define, a user level deployment configuration, in indeed defined.  The user level deployment can be found within the user's %AppData%

Comment: Ya I used an elevated cmd prompt to run it as well.

If it's a group policy that would be weird because it's only these new images affected and they are all in the same OU as the previous ones. I thought the same too and it was one of the first things I checked out. 

We have no group policy object designed to block this, maybe it's something locally but so far i haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The deployment configuration is going to be located in `C:\Windows\SUN\JAVA\DEPLOYMENT` more then likely.  Of course the deployment configuration file, literally could be in any location, depends on the person who configured the image.

Comment: So the deployment file doesn't exist in that location, it is in the users folder though. I found the deployment.properties file and put it's contents up in the first post. Had to hand jam it all. I did some googling earlier before I posted this and had the settings I was looking for regarding security levels saved but I don't see any in the file... I am running a search on the computer to see if there is another location somewhere

Comment: That folder DOES exist though, just empty

Comment: I found the solution, the file is in the main java directory under both program files directories and it has the options in there locking the settings. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The previous image we used allowed us to switch between "very high"
>   and "high" in the java security pane. This fixes the issue. Currently
>   on this new image it's grayed out, so we cannot access any of these
>   management sites.

This is due to the current configuration of the Windows image you are using.  You will have to find and locate the deployment.properties file and remove the following line from the file.

> I've tried numerous solutions after some extensive googling and
>   finding where java's settings are stored but the
>   (windows\sun\java\deployment) folder is empty.

```
deployment.security.level.locked
```

The Java configuration deployment file can literally be located in any location on the system.  You need to find the `deployment.config` file on the system.  This file defines the location of the properties of the Java configuration.  You should contact whomever created the Windows image in question for more information.

If you want to override the settings, create your own `deployment.config` and `deployment.properties`, then deploy them to `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment`.  You could also just add the sites to the exception list.

Comment: Ya the deployment.properties file was in the Program Files\Java\jre8\lib directory instead of the windows\sun\java\deployment location. I removed the "locked" settings as you described and it works. Just had to find the file like you said. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue today (Oct. 22, 2019) on a MacBook Pro running Catalina.  Specifically, after having installed the latest version of Java, the security settings "High" and "Very High" both were grayed out and could not be selected or changed by the user.

We tried the following and it worked!  We uninstalled Java (by running the installation app and selecting "Uninstall"), including deleting the cache files, and then reinstalled Java from scratch.  Now the security settings "High" and "Very High" are no longer grayed out, and they can be selected or changed.

We previously had installed Java on this Mac, but it somehow had disappeared and was no longer there.  So maybe something got glitched with Java along the way, and/or in installing the new version "over the top" (which always has worked).

Doing a complete Java uninstall, including removing the cache files, and then reinstalling fully fixed the problem.